# Fragment transaction after clicking item in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Here is my problem. I want to make fragment transaction when I click a single item in my `RecyclerView`. In pager adapter, I created `rootListFragment` which is a container for other `Fragments`. When `rootListFragment` is created it contains my fragment with `RecyclerView` which I named `ListFragment`. When I click single item I want to replace `rootListFragment` to `WebViewFragment` which contains for now only single text "Hello blank fragment". After this transaction, my `ListFragment` is still in front view. Do you know how to solve this problem? Here's my code.

RootListFragment:

```
public class RootListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_root_list, container, false);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.root_list_fragment, new ListFragment()).commit();

        return view;
    }

}
```

Part of `RecyclerView` with item click

```
public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ...

        public DataViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_list_fragment, new WebViewFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Screen of app after item click:
[image: screen]

Comment: Are you getting any error or you are not able to replace the fragment while clicking on item in RecyclerView

Comment: There are no errors. After clicking item in RecyclerView, rootListFragment still contains RecyclerView.

Comment: why do you want your ListFragment being destroy ? Because it will not be destroyed after calling replace method? what's your main goal?

Comment: Main goal is to replace recyclerView with new fragment after single item click. That's all. For now I have two fragments imposed in one view as you can see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your onclick method get your Context/activity value in your Adapter Constructor like this

```
   public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data)
{
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
    this.context=context;

}
```

and then in your onclick method put below code

```
context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_list_fragment, new WebViewFragment())
                .commit();
```